# How do I set an initial value for a text input when using a custom hook in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks

I have written a custom hook for an input to manage an input's changedhandler, unfocushandler and reset. I was wondering if it was possible to set an initial value so that when the user gets to the page, the inputs already have a value in it and then will be able to change it after.

This is the custom hook:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useInput = (validateValue, defaultVal) => {
  const [ enteredValue, setEnteredValue ] = useState('');
  const [ isTouched, setIsTouched ] = useState(false);

  const validInput = validateValue(enteredValue);
  const hasError = !validInput && isTouched;

  const  inputChangedHandler = event => {
    setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
  }

  const inputUnfocusHandler = event => {
    setIsTouched(true);
  }

  const reset = () => {
    setEnteredValue('');
    setIsTouched(false);
  }

  return {
    value: enteredValue,
    isValid: validInput,
    hasError,
    inputChangedHandler,
    inputUnfocusHandler,
    reset
  }
}

export default useInput;
```

And this is the input:

```
const {
    value: email,
    isValid: validEmail,
    hasError: emailError,
    inputChangedHandler: emailChangedHandler,
    inputUnfocusHandler: emailUnfocusHandler,
    reset: resetEmail
  } = useInput(isEmail);

<label htmlFor='name'>First Name</label>
<input 
   required
    type='text' 
    id='name' 
    value={fName}
    onChange={fnameChangedHandler}
    onBlur={fnameUnfocusHandler}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by add `defaultVal` when declare `enteredValue`:

```
const [ enteredValue, setEnteredValue ] = useState(defaultVal || "");
```

Comment: So I am getting a type error since I am also passing in a function for the validation. E.g. const isNotEmpty = (value) => value.trim() !== "";

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by react's [defaultValue](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) prop, it is especially useful when working with form elements.

So here is how to use it:

```
<input 
  required
  type="text"
  id="name"
  defaultValue="first name default value"
  onChange={fnameChangedHandler}
  onBlur={fnameUnfocusHandler}
/>
```